# Help using Linq to Query XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have this XML that I want to be able to pull out the Order#, Item(s), Qty, ItemPrice (Principal, Tax, could be others as well). Here is the XML (see below).  What I am having problems with is wiht the ItemPrice.  With in it you can 0 to Many Price Components, Tax, Principal Etc.  How can I pull those out into a single line output?

Right Now I can get orderNumber, ItemNumber, Qty...but when i pull the Price I get a line for tax and prinicpal.

One other question is what happens if in some instances Tax isn't there? I will get a null reference won't I? I want to try and handle those and just substitute 0.  Any suggestions are greatly appreicated.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SettlementReport>
<Order>
  <AmazonOrderID>105-6982537-6258888</AmazonOrderID> 
  <ShipmentID>MyShipmentIDTest1234</ShipmentID> 
  <MarketplaceName>Amazon.com</MarketplaceName> 
    <Fulfillment>
      <MerchantFulfillmentID>MyTestFulFillID12345</MerchantFulfillmentID> 
      <PostedDate>2008-12-15T19:33:04+00:00</PostedDate> 
        <Item>
          <AmazonOrderItemCode>13350774331938</AmazonOrderItemCode> 
          <SKU>U1409</SKU> 
          <Quantity>1</Quantity> 
            <ItemPrice>
                <Component>
                      <Type>Principal</Type> 
                      <Amount currency="USD">0.15</Amount> 
                  </Component>
                <Component>
                      <Type>Tax</Type> 
                      <Amount currency="USD">0.02</Amount> 
                  </Component>
              </ItemPrice>
          </Item>
          <Item>
            <AmazonOrderItemCode>13350774331939</AmazonOrderItemCode> 
            <SKU>U14010</SKU> 
            <Quantity>2</Quantity> 
            <ItemPrice>
                <Component>
                      <Type>Principal</Type> 
                      <Amount currency="USD">0.30</Amount> 
                  </Component>
                <Component>
                      <Type>Tax</Type> 
                      <Amount currency="USD">0.04</Amount> 
                  </Component>
              </ItemPrice>
          </Item>
      </Fulfillment>
  </Order>
</SettlementReport>
```

**My Code:**

```
            XDocument customer = XDocument.Load(@"C:\LinqToXML.xml");

            var orders = from amznorders in customer.Root.Elements("Order")
                         from amznfulfill in amznorders.Elements("Fulfillment")
                         from amznitems in amznfulfill.Elements("Item")
                         from amznitemprc in amznitems.Elements("ItemPrice").Elements("Component")
                             select new
                                        {
                                            OrderNumber = (string)amznorders.Element("AmazonOrderID"),
                                            ItemNumber = (string)amznitems.Element("AmazonOrderItemCode"),
                                            QTY = (string)amznitems.Element("Quantity"),
                                            //This is where I need help...if type = Principal set PriceAmount else Set PriceTax?//
                                            PriceAmount = (string)amznitemprc.Element("Amount")
                                            //Address1 = (string)address1.Element("Address1")
                                     };

            foreach (var order in orders)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Order: {0} ItemNumber: {1} QTY: {2} PriceAmount: {3} ", order.OrderNumber, order.ItemNumber, order.QTY, order.PriceAmount);

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doable, though admittedly a bit awkward. I'd probably use a pair of let variables hold the sub-components I want (assuming you only want those two specific values).

Edited to remove the lets due to problem with the Where clause. I don't *think* there's a problem with the Where in the select, but it may have the same problem.

```
var orders = from amznorders in customer.Root.Elements("Order")    
             from amznfulfill in amznorders.Elements("Fulfillment")    
             from amznitems in amznfulfill.Elements("Item")    
             from amznitemprc in amznitems.Elements("ItemPrice").Elements("Component")    
             select new    
                         {    
                                OrderNumber = (string)amznorders.Element("AmazonOrderID"),    
                                ItemNumber = (string)amznitems.Element("AmazonOrderItemCode"),    
                                Qty = (string)amznitems.Element("Quantity"),
                                PriceAmount = amznitemprc.Where(xe => xe.Element("Type").Value == "Principal").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                                TaxAmount = amxnitemprc.Where(xe => xe.Element("Type").Value == "Tax").FirstOrDefault() == null ? string.Empty : amxnitemprc.Where(xe => xe.Element("Type").Value == "Tax").FirstOrDefault(),
                                TotalItemPrice = amznitemprc.Sum(xe => decimal.Parse(xe.Element("Amount").Value)).ToString(),
                                //Address1 = (string)address1.Element("Address1")    
                         };
```

Comment: Jacob, would it be better to use a different method? I am not stuck on Linq, just thought I should try to take advantage of it.

Thanks for the tip I will check it out.

Comment: When I try it the Where in the let variables don't seem to be recognized.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if the Where would register later on. I'm not in a place I can test it until tomorrow, but I'll edit something in. It'll be a bit complex, though.